# C++ destructor for class contains array of ptr to objects

Tags: c++, destructor

For example if we have 2 classes

```
class A{
  int size;
  A** arr;
}
class B{
  int size;
  A** arr;
}
```

For A's constructor I wrote:

```
A::A(){
  this->arr=new A* [20];
}
```

For B's constructor I wrote:

```
B:B(){
  this->arr=new A* [20];
}
```

For A's destroctor I wrote:

```
A:~A(){
  for(int i=0;i<this->size;i++){
    delete this->arr[i];
  }
  delete [] this->arr;
}
```

For B's destructor I wrote:

```
  B:~B(){
  for(int i=0;i<this->size;i++){
    delete this->arr[i];
  }
  delete [] this->arr;
}
```

Note that the size will grow as I put more obj into the arr.
Now my question is, while I am testing, there's nothing wrong, but after the main program returns, it gives me segfault?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This would be `A`-ception if you actually allocated the nested arrays, which brings us to your UB... And yes, `size` has likewise indeterminate value.

Comment: @LogicStuff,well there's nothing wrong while I am testing the program..

Comment: @NeoA The destructor is doing its job -- it is not to blame.  The problem is that you're probably making the destructor destroy unallocated memory, or a double-deallocation of the same memory by not implementing a correct copy constructor and / or assignment operator.  Also please post a [mcve] so that others need not have to ask you about `size` variables or what you're doing between the calls to when you create the object and when you destroy the object.

Comment: Don't get mad at me, but... ehm, in fact, don't answer this question at all; it's not for my sake. Just read it. So, any reason you're not using vectors?

Comment: @NeoA Again, the problem is not the destructor.  The destructor is revealing that you fouled up the memory somewhere else.  Commenting out the destructor is the same as putting a piece of tape on your car dashboard warning light, thinking that the problem has been fixed with your car.  So there is nothing to "fix" in your destructor.  The fix should be applied to the rest of your code (which you have not shown us).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my code is about 300 lines in total..I am afraid no one is interested in reading my code and point out my problem

Comment: @MrLister Why would I be mad? the reason is that I cannot use vector at this point

Comment: @NeoA So what are we to do then?  Maybe you should delete your question, as it will have no value.  The destructor is not the problem, but that's what you want us to focus on.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like a classic case of not implementing the copy constructor and passing an instance by copy. You should really read an article or two about memory management in c++, or use shared_ptr/unique_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize size in the constructor, too.

```
A::A(){
   this->size=20;
   this->arr=new A* [20];
}
```

same for B

Comment: No, size is the actual number of A I put in the arr, 20 is the capacity it should be. Sorry for the confusion